# MySQL Complex query not returning right results

Tags: php, mysql, null

I have the following query:

```
'SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN taxi ON taxi.taxiID = posts.postID
    WHERE (taxi.value = 1 AND taxi.userID ='.$userID.') 
    AND ??????????????
    ORDER BY taxi.ID DESC
    LIMIT 10'
```

The way the site works is the user can tag posts as being "liked". When a post is liked, the taxi table is given a new row with taxiID being the same as postID, userID to store the user that liked the post, and `value` which is set to 1. Disliking a post sets `value` to 0.

I want to display all posts where `value` is 1 and `userID` is `$userID` - check. However, I also want the query to display all the posts where the user hasn't liked a post yet. Thing is, if the user hasn't liked a post yet, `userID` is `NULL` with a corresponding `value` of `NULL`. If I query for that, I'll be skipping those posts that other users have liked but the user hasn't.

Here's the `taxi` table:

```
ID    taxiID    userID    value
1     1         1         1
2     1         6         1
3     1         4         0
4     2         1         0
5     2         6         1
6     2         4         0
7     3         6         1
8     3         4         0
```

Assuming `$userID` is 1, my query ought to display `taxiID` 1 and 3 (because user 1 liked `ID` 1 AND hasn't liked or disliked `taxiID` 3.

The code I've posted will only result in displaying `taxiID` 1.

The question is, what is my missing line in my query supposed to be given the above?

Comment: What is up with the AND ???????

Comment: taxi.ID 3 has taxi.value set to 0, so it wouldn't be returned.

Comment: That is the line of code I can't figure out.

Comment: Jake, I'm looking to return taxi.ID 3 because userID 1 did not set any value for it. Only Users 4 and 6 have set values.

Comment: It sounds to me like you just want to show all posts - those the user has liked, and those the user hasn't liked. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: In that case, why not just do `select * from taxi order by taxi.id desc limit 10`? I don't see why you even need a `where`

Comment: Because I don't want to display the ones User 1 disliked.

Comment: Ah, then try `SELECT * from taxi WHERE taxi.value is not null and taxi.value = 0 ORDER by taxi.id DESC LIMIT 10`

Comment: That will only return the rows the user disliked, which is not what I want

Comment: Whoops, I meant `taxi.value != 0` instead of `taxi.value = 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to find all `taxiID` that the use has not disliked:

```
SELECT taxiID 
FROM taxi
GROUP BY taxiID
HAVING taxiID NOT IN 
      ( SELECT taxiID
        FROM taxi 
        WHERE userID = '.$userID.'
          AND value = 0
      )
ORDER BY taxiID DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Test in [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2f17/2)

---

You probably have a `post` table, so it would be better to use:

```
SELECT *                               --- whatever columns from `post` table
FROM post
WHERE postID NOT IN                     
      ( SELECT taxiID
        FROM taxi 
        WHERE userID = '.$userID.'
          AND value = 0
      )
ORDER BY postID 
LIMIT 10
```

---

If that `taxi.taxiID` means `postID`, then you should rename it to `taxi.postID`. It's very confusing as it is.

Comment: Does it return `taxiID = 2` ?

Comment: It returns absolutely everything.

Comment: It returns taxiID 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. I want only taxiID 1 and 3 (assuming userID is 1)

Comment: Try the link to the test. You probably use `taxi.ID` somewhere instead of my `taxiID`

Comment: You're right. it was the limit that was stopping it from showing more results. There's still the question of what about showing the posts that aren't in the table at all (ex: taxiID 4 which no user has liked or disliked at all and as such, doesn't appear in the table)?

Comment: I updated my query to show that taxiID = postID in the posts table.

Comment: Okay, I'm told your answer is inefficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: Is it slow? I would expect such a query to be very fast with proper indexing on `taxi` table.

Comment: No, it's very fast. However, everyone here says it is an inefficient query and they keep trying to change the query rather than solve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220564/mysql-count-complex-query-results

Comment: First, the query you have posted in that question is different than both of my suggestions here. Second, there you want to count, not show all postIDs. And thitrd, you have 3 answers that are essentially this 2nd query of mine, with the only chang being in the Select list: `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` Those 3 answers (by @kjones, @Mosty and @Vutukuri) are all correct. So, you are probably doing something wrong in your PHP code.

Comment: It's only different in that value is null instead of 0 and I'm counting posts instead of selecting taxi - the rest is exactly the same. That means that in essence, the spirit of the query is the same so if that query is inefficient, so is this one.

I suppose if inefficiency is the only way to get what I want, then so be it. Your answer here however, still stands as correct and functioning so thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I had this as a comment, but I think it's my final answer:

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN taxi ON taxi.taxiID = posts.postID
WHERE (taxi.value != 0 AND taxi.userID ='.$userID.') 
OR taxi.value is null
ORDER BY taxi.ID DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Ok, this is what should happen with the above query:

1. Get all posts
2. Add the info from the taxi table, and associate taxi data with post data by postID
3. Only show if taxi.value isn't 0 (meaning it can be null or 1) AND if the userID is the same as our variable

Comment: I updated my query to show that taxi is subserviant to posts. I need to show all posts that user 1 liked AND all posts where user 1 did not like and did not dislike. Likes and dislikes are stored in taxi.

Comment: Ok, edited it one more time. If that doesn't work, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming taxi.taxiID is the same as post.ID and you're looking to select all posts not tagged by a user yet, try:

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE ID NOT IN
(SELECT taxiID FROM taxi WHERE userID = 1)
```

this is for user with an ID=1 of course.