# MySQL count complex query results?

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have the following query:

```
$count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post GROUP BY ID
HAVING ID NOT IN (SELECT taxiID FROM taxi WHERE userID = '.$userID.' AND value IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY postID), OBJECT);
```

Count contains this:

```
count = Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) [10] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) [11] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) [12] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) [13] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) [14] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) [15] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) [16] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) [17] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) [18] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) [19] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 1 )
```

I need to count the number of results delivered by the above. Thing is, I have no idea how to use the result!

I had this code but now it won't work:

```
<?php if($count[0]->{'COUNT(*)'} > 10){ ?
    echo "Load More";
}else { 
    echo "Nothing to load";
} ?>
```

$count should be more than 10 and my php should echo Load More but it is echoing Nothing to load.

The taxi table looks like this:

```
ID    taxiID    userID    value
1     1         1         1
2     1         6         1
3     1         4         0
4     2         1         0
5     2         6         1
6     2         4         0
7     3         6         1
8     3         4         0
```

The post table looks like this:

```
ID    postID    randomNum
1     1         564
2     2         789
3     3         234
4     4         845
5     5         089
```

Assuming $userID is 1, the query returns postID 1,3,4,5 (1 is liked, 3 is not liked and not disliked by user 1, 4 and 5 are not liked and not disliked by any user). Therefore $count should contain 4 (4 results are found).

If my query is inefficient, how do I adapt it to be efficient?

Ultimately, the question is how do I do something like:

```
if ($count > 10) {}
```

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) should work with the query. What's the error message that you are getting?

Comment: how about mysql_num_rows

Comment: Like SuperNoob suggests, I find it easier to return the num_rows than to use the mysql COUNT

Comment: COUNT(*) is probably more efficient than mysql_num_rows() since the result set has to be return from the database for mysql_num_rows() to work.

Comment: COUNT won't work. I get an array with with increment keys with values of 1 in each. [1] => 1 [2] => 1 and so on.

Comment: Could you articulate what the query is trying to count?

Comment: Since you're grouping by ID (and assuming IDs are unique as they usually are) your COUNT will return 1 for each row.

You have to remember that HAVING applies to the result of the GROUP BY, i.e. it will not affect the COUNT. If you wanted to set a condition on what gets counted you need to use a WHERE.

Comment: It is counting all posts that the user has not liked or disliked. likes and dislikes are stored in the taxi table. taxi.taxiID matches post.ID. Hence if the userID with any value that isn't null is found, ignore that post.ID. I am counting those post.ID which are not ignored. Using SELECT, I get hundreds of results, but using COUNT, I am not getting the correct output of "load more"

Comment: I am grouping by ID because without the grouping, ID repeats because more than 1 user can like or dislike the same post.ID. I want to output the ID once total, not once for each user in the database.

Comment: The question however remains. You can see my array is more than ten results long yet my output says Nothing to load when it should say Load More.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is, your query isn't returning what you think it returns (it always helps to run you query standalone, to see if the result set is what you expect).

Right, let's break this down.

> It is counting all posts that the user has not liked or disliked. likes and dislikes are stored in the taxi table. taxi.taxiID matches post.ID. Hence if the userID with any value that isn't null is found, ignore that post.ID. I am counting those post.ID which are not ignored

You're trying count all posts that **don't** have a matching record in the taxi table, for that userID. What you want here is to `JOIN` the tables and get those rows in `post` that would normally be excluded by the join. This is achieved by an left outer join

(**edited**)

```
SELECT p.ID, t.taxiID
FROM post p LEFT OUTER JOIN taxi t ON p.ID = t.taxiID AND t.userID = '.$user.'
HAVING t.taxiID IS NULL
```

That `HAVING` clause is saying: only those rows in the resultset that didn't have a corresponding t.taxiID.

If you run this query and get the expected set of rows (posts that do not have likes or dislikes by that user) THEN you can add an outer query to count the number of returned rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM (
    SELECT p.ID, t.taxiID
    FROM post p LEFT OUTER JOIN taxi t ON p.ID = t.taxiID AND t.userID = '.$user.'
    HAVING t.taxiID IS NULL
) a
```

This should return a single scalar named count. In this case you'll be able to say:

```
if ($count[0]->count > 10) { blah blah blah }
```

(**2nd edit**) This inner query will get you those posts that have either value = 1 in the taxi table, or no value at all, which results in 4 being returned for your example:

```
SELECT p.ID, t.taxiID, t.value
FROM post p LEFT OUTER JOIN taxi t ON p.ID = t.taxiID AND t.userID = '.$user.'
HAVING t.taxiID IS NULL OR t.value = 1
```

Comment: You may also be able to just run it as the inner query with the `COUNT(*) as count` replacing the `*`, but I don't remember how this interacts with the HAVING clause.

Comment: This doesn't work. No results are found. See updated question with layout of taxi and post tables. Assuming $user is 1, the query should find postID 1,3,4,5 thus count should be 4. Your solution results in count being 0.

Comment: I have fixed and edited the SQL by loading the data into a test database and running it. The main difference is that the test for userID has moved to the ON clause of the LEFT JOIN, and the test for value IS NULL has been removed (I recommend a NOT NULL constraint on this column).

You'll find that the correct answer for $user = 1 is actually 3, since they have made values for postIDs 1 and 2.

Comment: yes but I am looking for all posted that have value 1 AND all posts that don't have any values at all. Your query is finding all null values only. This means I'm missing an "AND value = 1" somewhere correct?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Mind this wasn't communicated all that well in your description. I've updated the answer to get this in.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to know how many results would have been returned WITHOUT the LIMIT clause, according to the MySQL documentation:

> A SELECT statement may include a LIMIT clause to restrict the number
>   of rows the server returns to the client. In some cases, it is
>   desirable to know how many rows the statement would have returned
>   without the LIMIT, but without running the statement again. To obtain
>   this row count, include a SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option in the SELECT
>   statement, and then invoke FOUND_ROWS() afterward:

```
mysql> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name
    -> WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
mysql> SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post
WHERE postID NOT IN                     
  ( SELECT taxiID
    FROM taxi 
    WHERE userID = '.$userID.'
      AND value = 0
  ) 
ORDER BY postID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post
WHERE postID NOT IN                     
  ( SELECT taxiID
    FROM taxi 
    WHERE userID = '.$userID.'
      AND value = 0
  )
```

Can you also provide us with the error message if this does not work?

Comment: I get an array. I need a numeric value.

Comment: You should be able to initialize a variable with the integer value of your count directly from the array that is returned.

Comment: So `COUNT(*)` is working correctly, and you have a new question.  You should remove the part where you state that `COUNT(*)` is not working.

Comment: Duely noted. I suppose the better question is, how do I check if $count is greater than 10?

Comment: @kjones: +1 this is correct. Perhaps you can add an alias, eg.: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM ...` so it's easier for the OP to retrieve the `cnt` in the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not this?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post
WHERE postID NOT IN (
  SELECT taxiID FROM taxi 
  WHERE userID = '.$userID.' AND value = 0
)
LIMIT 10
```

Note there is no need to perform an `order by` if you are only looking for the count. Also note you have a `limit` there so the result won't have more than 10 records. Not sure if that is the idea.

Comment: you're right, if forgot to remove LIMIT. However, COUNT doesn't work.

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, count works perfectly. You're messing things up with your PHP code, which you haven't provided.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and it was dead simple:

```
if (count($count) > 10) {}
```

Comment: This is indeed a very inefficient way of doing it, yes. Just cause it works doesn't mean it's right.

Comment: I agree it is, but without a solution to my query I have no alternative.